# Maths revision program

Tags: bash, math

I have created a program that will randomly select two numbers out of a range and ask a multiplication question from it.
It looks very messy and repetitive.

What I would like help with is "How would I make my code less repetitive and easier to understand"
Here is my code... 
**https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fa95b8493ef4d495f49a**

Comment: Have a look at arrays in bash. Better create an array with 10 elements than 10 variables.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the repetitiveness by using a `for` loop. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html

Here is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Input the range you want to practice. For example: 1-12, 4-9, 9-11: " range

QUESTIONS=0
CORRECT=0

for i in {1..5}; do
  let QUESTIONS++
  n1=$(shuf -i $range -n 1)
  n2=$(shuf -i $range -n 1)
  realans=$((n1 * n2))
  read -p "${n1} x ${n2}? " ans
  if [[ $ans -eq $realans ]]; then
    let CORRECT++
    echo "Correct! ${n1} x ${n2} is ${realans}."
  else
    echo "Incorrect. ${n1} x ${n2} is ${realans}."
  fi
done

echo "You got ${CORRECT} out of ${QUESTIONS} questions correct!"
```

I simplified the program and opted for `read` instead of `zentity` for simplicity and to keep both the input and output in the terminal. I have also demonstrated usage of `let var++` which is a cleaner, more modern way of incrementing a counter.

Comment: Nice conversion.  While `let` is cleaner, note that it's not POSIX.  The only non-POSIX extensions in this answer are `[[ ... ]]` and `let` and `{1..5}`.  Nothing wrong with that.  I just point it out because in some environments POSIX is required, so I've gotten in the habit of coding to `/bin/sh` when possible.  On many systems `/bin/sh` is much smaller (1/8 the size) and faster than `bash`.